# Detect all the change events based on document

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, onchange

I'm using PJAX, so my html content is from AJAX,

which means my elements are dymanic, I couldn't use $('input').on('change')

(unless I use it every time I got the new content from AJAX )

My idea is using $(document).on() so I can keep tracking the events,

but how do I detect something is on change when I using $(document).on()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind to a core ajax complete event...

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler." );
});
```

This sets up a global callback for all AJAX complete operations.

You can perform some activity here regarding the event.

Once the AJAX handler is setup, you can re register a global event handler on change event to all elements

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $("input,textarea,select").off("change").on("change",function()
  {
      //dom something 
  });
});
```

Hope it helps!